# How can I block Cross-site Scripting (XSS) through interceptor in proxy tool in ASP.Net

Tags: xss

I have page that with textbox's for first and last name.
When i test the page and update the last name with Doe%uff1cscript%uff1ealert%uff0812345%uff09%uff1c/script%uff1 using interceptor in proxy tool like BURP suite the last name gets stored as <script>alert（12345）</script> in the database.

I have tried to use microsoft antixss library but that did not work. Below is the code I used:
Dim Lname As String = Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode(txtLName.Text)

Does anyone have a suggestions one how I can prevent this?

Comment: Need any more help with this? If so I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply HTML encode on **output**, not when it is stored.

e.g. `<` becomes `&lt;`, `&` becomes `&amp;`.

See the [OWASP XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) for further details.

In .NET you can use `Server.HTMLEncode` or `<%:myVar %>` in views to do this.